# Installed Build Tools revision 31.0.0 is corrupted

Tags: android, cordova

I'm using Cordova to build an Android app because I don't know the first thing about Android.

I performed the following steps to create and run a Cordova app:

- Install JDK 8
- Install Gradle
- Install Android Studio
- Install SDK version 28 using SDK Manager within Android Studio (I'm targeting Fire TV devices)
- `npm install -g cordova`
- `cordova create app`
- `cd app`
- `npm i`
- `cordova platform add android@9.0.0` (to target API level 28)
- `cordova run android`

This is the end of the output from the last command:

```
Build-tool 31.0.0 is missing DX at /Users/steve.taylor/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/31.0.0/dx

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Installed Build Tools revision 31.0.0 is corrupted. Remove and install again using the SDK Manager.
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the SDK, but I still get the error that suggests build tools are corrupted. Are the build tools actually corrupted, or is there some magical undocumented sequence of commands I have to run to get it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the SDK tools are actually broken, or not what Cordova or Gradle expect.

Fix (on macOS):

```sh
cp ~/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/31.0.0/lib/d8.jar \
   ~/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/31.0.0/lib/dx.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Open Your SDK Path: C:\Users<user name>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools<your build-tools number error>

find file `d8` rename is to `dx`

Open **lib** folder : C:\Users<user name>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools<your build-tools number error>\lib

once again find file `d8` rename is to `dx`

and try again

```
yarn android
```